# Youtube API - Set the Thumbnail of Video (python)

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

**Is it possible to specify your own thumbnail for a video that has been uploaded via the YouTube API?**

Using the most recent version of the Python Library, it appears that I can create and set the thumbnail of my media group before inserting a video entry to YouTube - however the thumbnail specified does NOT get set on the video itself.

I'm using code similar to this:

```
from gdata import media
from gdata.youtube import YouTubeVideoEntry
from gdata.youtube.service import YouTubeService

# Create a thumbnail and pass it to my media group
thumbnail = media.Thumbnail(url='http://valid_image_url.jpg')
media_group = media.Group(thumbnail=thumbnail, title='foo', ...)

# Use the media group to create a video entry
entry = YouTubeVideoEntry(media=media_group)

# Create a service instance and use it to login
service = YouTubeService(...)
service.ClientLogin(...)

# Get video file
file = open('/path_to_video.mp4', 'rb')

# Push the video to YouTube
service.InsertVideoEntry(
    entry,
    file
)

# Close the file
file.close()
```

Comment: It should be noted for anyone who happens to see this question now, this is no longer the case. It is possible to set a video thumbnail using the youtube api, see here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** Using the standard YouTube API, you cannot programatically set a thumbnail for your video.

However, if you are a [content partner](http://www.youtube.com/partners) and have access the [YouTube CMS](https://cms.youtube.com/partner_documentation?document=content_and_rights_administration_feed_shows_and_movies#tag_video_artwork) (which your partner manager can enable), you can apparently set your video artwork from there. I'll post details as I run through this process.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set ??

Comment: Do please add new answers as the API extends to allow new functionality, rather than comment bombing 11 year old answers. We've moved on, you clearly have context.  Thanks.