# Video uploaded to youtube has low quality preview thumbnail

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I have an iphone application that uploads videos to youtube. It uploads the video files without a problem. But there is an issue that the thumbnail preview image is of very low quality.

My question is this, is it possible using the youtube api to set a different preview image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube API - Set the Thumbnail of Video (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654719/youtube-api-set-the-thumbnail-of-video-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. this is not possible with the Standard API.

See this answer for possible ways forward. [Youtube API - Set the Thumbnail of video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654719/youtube-api-set-the-thumbnail-of-video-python)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: That's not a critique, its the current state of affairs, it can't be done with the API.  So it's quite precisely an answer, the correct answer. --- The question is also a duplicate, that's addressed as a comment. - The OP is asking how to set a thumbnail image via the API, they can't ... what more can be said?

Comment: What about https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set ?

Comment: Add an answer if it's now possible. @MCCCS